# How do I do a typedef in mojo?

Tags: types, declaration, typedef, mojolang

I want to implement a class with a property whose type I can change globally at compile time.
For example,

```
let ID_TYPE = Int

@value
struct MyStruct:
    var a: ID_TYPE
```

However, `let` seems not to be applicable to define types, as I receive the error `invalid call to '__del__': argument #0 cannot be converted from 'Int' to 'Int'mojo`

What can I do to avoid having to manually change all places where the `ID_TYPE` occurs in my code when I change e.g. from `Int` to `Uint8`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compile-time variables can be set via the [`alias` keyword](https://docs.modular.com/mojo/manual/parameters/#alias-named-parameter-expressions). Then, the example reads as follows:

```
alias ID_TYPE = Int

@value
struct MyStruct:
    var a: ID_TYPE
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to change it during compile time is to use compile-time defines, for example:

```
from sys.param_env import is_defined
from tensor import Tensor, TensorSpec

alias float_type: DType = DType.float32 if is_defined["FLOAT32"]() else DType.float64

let spec = TensorSpec(float_type, 256, 256)
var image = Tensor[float_type](spec)
```

then during compilation you can do:

```
mojo -D FLOAT_32 main.mojo
```

you can read more here: https://docs.modular.com/mojo/stdlib/sys/param_env.html